# How to work reliably with XmlReader

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader

I'm using the [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) class, the forward-only reader. A method I'm calling moves the cursor as a side-effect. However, sometimes the method throws an exception, and leaves the cursor somewhere unexpected. How can I handle that?

```
xml.ReadStartElement("root");

if (xml.IsStartElement("Results"))
{
    try
    {
        results = Results.FromXml(xml);
        // if method successful, it reads past the closing tag of the 'Results' element
    }
    catch
    {
        results = null;
        // I want to manually move the cursor past the closing tag of the 'Results' element.
    }
}
```

Example document

```
<root>
    <results>
        <arbitaryxml/>
    </results>*
    <signatures>
```

If the Results.FromXml method is successful, the cursor gets left at *. However if it fails, it might be left anywhere inside the results element. I want my catch block to make sure the cursor is advanced to *. (NB. The next element isn't always called 'signatures').

I found this quite hard to explain. Please ask if it needs clarification, I can give more examples.

Comment: I feel like an exception generally shouldn't be a part of the expected flow of the program. They are supposed to be planned for, yes, but I feel like you should do some checking to prevent the exception from being thrown in the first place.

Comment: On what grounds can it fail? I'd address the cause and not the symptoms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jim is right, the [ReadSubtree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree.aspx) method works, although it's a tad fiddly:

```
if (xml.IsStartElement("Results"))
{
    // Be careful so that the cursor will be left after the closing tag of the 'Results' element, even if Results.FromXml throws.

    using (XmlReader resultsElement = xml.ReadSubtree())
    {
        resultsElement.Read();
        try 
        {
            results = Results.FromXml(resultsElement);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Reading results xml went wrong {0}", e.Message);
        }
    }

    xml.ReadEndElement();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ReadSubtree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree.aspx) method, which will do what you want. Actually, it positions to the end element node, but it accomplishes what you want. Typically, you write something like:

```
XmlReader resultsReader = reader.ReadSubtree();
while (resultsReader.Read())
{
    // process results node here
}
```

After `ReadSubtree` returns, a call to `reader.Read` will return the `</results>` EndElement node. So if processing the results throws an exception, you're still in the right place.

If `ReadSubtree` throws an exception, that's of course unrecoverable. That indicates an error in the XML, which as far as I've been able to determine, isn't reliably recoverable using `XmlReader`.